# Android database error, from retrieving Blob type.

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I'm getting an error while I run this Query:

```
public List<byte[]> getImageBlobs() {
        List<byte[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT imageBlob FROM boardgames", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            list.add(cursor.getBlob(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
}
```

Database structure from DB Browser for SQLite

[image]

From logcat:

```
03-06 10:43:51.342 10469-10469/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: imageBlob
03-06 10:43:51.343 10469-10469/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.boardgamehelper.boardgamehelper, PID: 10469
                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: imageBlob (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT imageBlob FROM boardgames
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

Comment: Reinstall application and try again.

Comment: Adb pull down the db and look at the structure of the table-  I suspect your create query was wrong or you had an old version of the table without that column and didn't update it correctly.

Comment: @ahmadaghazadeh what application? the app or Sqlite browser

Comment: Do you have changed the structure of your database?

Comment: yes, i fixed it. i had to clear data on the app

Comment: make sure you have `imageBlob` column in your table: the easiest way to do that is, just for testing, query for "select * from boardgames" and call `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()`

Comment: This error occurred when column name not exists into your database, make sure your database is upgraded or not after the change in the table. You have to reset whenever your table has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the database structure changes need to be removed and re-created database.
Reinstall application and try again.

Then remove and reinstall the program to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Clear data is not a good idea. If your application is already in production. You should be using ALTER statement and adding the column in the onUpgrade() of the class extending SQLiteOpenHelper
Do not forget to update the database version whenever you alter the tables schema.